# X_axis ticks showing in thousands because of arange

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
%matplotlib inline

N = norm.cdf

def BS_CALL(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + sigma**2/2)*T) / (sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(T)
    return S * N(d1) - K * np.exp(-r*T)* N(d2)

def BS_PUT(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + sigma**2/2)*T) / (sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sigma* np.sqrt(T)
    return K*np.exp(-r*T)*N(-d2) - S*N(-d1)


K = 100
r = 0.1
T = 1
sigma = 0.3

S = np.arange(1,300,.1)

calls = [BS_CALL(s, K, T, r, sigma) for s in S]
call_intrinsic = [s-K if(s>K) else 0 for s in S]
puts = [BS_PUT(s, K, T, r, sigma) for s in S]


plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot( calls, label='Call Value')
plt.plot(call_intrinsic, label="Intrinsic Value")
plt.xlabel('$S_0$')
plt.ylabel(' Value')
plt.legend()
```

See the X ticks

[image]

I wanted the X ticks to have figures from 0.1 to 300. I wanted the plot's X axis to have the same range but seems like the 0.1 in arange is working things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `S` as `x` parameter of `plot`:

```
...
plt.plot(S, calls, label='Call Value')
plt.plot(S, call_intrinsic, label="Intrinsic Value")
...
```

If you don't pass 2 data values, `plot` consider the values are those of `y` (your code). If you pass two, the first is `x` and the second `y` (the code above).

Output:

[image]